# how do I populate a List<T> from multiple methods with Task<List<T>>?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm still trying to get a handle on the new async/await operators. I have several async methods that return Task> that I plan to use to capture issues with a resultset - the primary purpose is that multiple checks can occur concurrently.

As it is, when I do await Task.WhenAll() I get a List[] that I have to run through to get what I want. I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this - any help would be appreciated!

Here is my test code (I'm using Linqpad as a test bed):
results is the List[], while ErrorList is what I'd like it to look like. Thanks again!

```
async Task Main()
{
    var results = await Task.WhenAll (FirstCheck(), SecondCheck());
    var ErrorList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var d in results)
    {
        foreach (var i in d)
        {
            ErrorList.Add(string.Format("error: {0}",i));
        }
    }
    results.Dump();
    ErrorList.Dump();
}

async Task<List<string>> FirstCheck()
{
    List<string> Errors = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
    return Errors;
}

  async Task<List<string>> SecondCheck()
{
    List<string> Errors = new List<string>{"a","b","c"};
    return Errors;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to convert a `List<string>[]` into an `IEnumerable<string>`, which isn't async-specific... plain LINQ will do it:

```
var errors = results.SelectMany(x => x);
```

That will flatten the array of lists to just a single sequence.

Comment: thank you! I never would have thought it would be that simple - just one of those things I hadn't encountered yet.